# Publish External Resources with SWF in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript

Is there a way to load graphics externally when in development but package the graphics into the project's swf when it is published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely no built-in way of doing that.  You could build a class that handles supplying assets to your views.  The class would be smart enough to be able to alternatively instantiate objects either from a library asset or an externally-loaded asset.  That way, all you would need to have is a toggle that will determine if the assets are loaded externally or not.  If the toggle is set to external, then your application will know to preload the assets.  Either way, your custom asset class will know how to instantiate each object you need.